# CSS: Position text in the middle of the page

Tags: css, text, positioning

I would like to position a `<h1>` in the middle of any user's page. I have been searching the internet and they all position it in the incorrect place. Thank you!
UPDATE: I mean vertical and horizontal! In the exact middle!
ALSO: There is **nothing** else on the page.

Comment: Do you mean both vertical and horizontal centering?

Comment: Is there anything else on the page?

Comment: Nope. Just a background image.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute` and `top`-`margin-top` to vertically align something whose height you know, and `line-height` to give a single line of text a known height with the text in the middle:

```css
h1 {
    left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Comment: Then you replace the html by "<h1>Hello world!<br/>I'm evil!</h1>" ... and madness return ;) So I guess the Javascript is the only way ?

Comment: @proxygear: I’d use the `vertical-align` hack in that case (`<div>` wrapper, empty `inline-block` and `100%` height `::before`, `inline-block` `<h1>`, `vertical-align: middle;` on both)

Answer (score 44):

Here's a method using [`display:flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>centered text!</div>
</div>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/pythagoras1357/pen/ZOPLoY)
[Check Browser Compatability](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Answer (score 4):

Even though you've accepted an answer, I want to post this method. I use jQuery to center it vertically instead of css (although both of these methods work). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/gzgXT/) is a fiddle, and I'll post the code here anyways.

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('h1').css({ 'width':'100%', 'text-align':'center' });
  var h1 = $('h1').height();
  var h = h1/2;
  var w1 = $(window).height();
  var w = w1/2;
  var m = w - h
  $('h1').css("margin-top",m + "px")
});
```

This takes the height of the viewport, divides it by two, subtracts half the height of the h1, and sets that number to the `margin-top` of the h1. The beauty of this method is that it works on multiple-line `h1`s.

**EDIT:** I modified it so that it centered it every time the window is resized.

Comment: Oh, cool! I've always wanted to get into jQuery; I should probably learn it :P

Comment: If you are using this positioning function, you should also attach it to the window resize event. For mobile vertical/horizontal switch but also to avoid awkward result when user just resize his browser window ;)